# Resized text on computer but not on phone HTML

Tags: android, html, css, font-size

I want to resize my text according to the size on the screen. By using the new vw and vh seems to work fine on my PC, but when I am accessing the website from my phone the text remains the same. i.e: it's huge for my phone screen. Here is my code:

```
#aboutMe {
color: white;
font-style: italic;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 7vw 10px 5px 39vw;
font-size: 2.5vw;
}
```

Any guesses to how to solve this issue?

Comment: What browser are you using on your phone?

Comment: What broswer are you using and what phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use something like
    `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`in your HTML?

Comment: No, I didn't used that one

Answer (score 1):

you should avoid using px use em insted in the margin property.
May it helps.